# Check if an item exists with DynamoDbContext?

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is there a way to check if an item exists in DynamoDbContext that does not return the item?  Currently, in .NET I am using `Load`, but this returns the item.  Is there a method that just returns true or false based on existence?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21703952/775544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

March 2018: I've done a search of the current assembly **AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2, Version=3.3.0.0** and can't find any method that resembles an **EXISTS** style method.

Per the comment above from Anthony Neace, and the answer by Sony Kadavan:

> The bottleneck is in latency to reach the Dynamo DB servers (REST API)
>   and in fetching from the index. So Getting and checking will be
>   similar speed.
>   [Quickly query a table if it contains a key (DynamoDB and Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792529/quickly-query-a-table-if-it-contains-a-key-dynamodb-and-java/21703952#21703952)

So I believe the answer is no there's no such method. You can write your own wrapper that gets the item (maybe get just one attribute) and return a boolean indicating if the item exists or not.

This is from the [AWS doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryMidLevelDotNet.html) and shows how to query a table returning a defined set of attributes:

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "Reply");
DateTime twoWeeksAgoDate = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
QueryOperationConfig config = new QueryOperationConfig()
{
  HashKey = "DynamoDB Thread 2", //Partition key
  AttributesToGet = new List<string> 
    { "Subject", "ReplyDateTime", "PostedBy" },
  ConsistentRead = true,
  Filter = new RangeFilter(QueryOperator.GreaterThan, twoWeeksAgoDate)
};

Search search = table.Query(config);
```

In your case just get a single attribute and returns a true/false depending on whether you got the item or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an expression as below and use in your query. And then you can check the count.

```
var expression = new Expression
{
  ExpressionStatement = "attribute_exists(attributeName)"
};
```